# makefile: run in parallel, starting in sequence

Tags: makefile

I am trying to start 3 servers(and Envoy loadbalancer) and then run a client, but how do you do it in a makefile?

I have this makefile:

```
envoy:
    envoy -c envoy.yaml
server1:
    go run ./server1/main.go
server2:
    go run ./server2/main.go
server3:
    go run ./server3/main.go

loadbalancer: envoy server1 server2 server3
    go run ./client/main.go
```

But it is stuck in stdout from the envoy command - I need also to start the 3 servers, do you know how?

Thanks

Comment: `envoy -c envoy.yaml &` maybe? Also, by default, `make` will run the first target, so you probably want your last rule first.

Comment: Why do you want to use `make` for this?  `make` can surely do it, but this seems like a case that would be better served by an ordinary shell script.

Comment: Right, I will do that - just wanted to see if I could keep it all in one file.